# Sorting counting catergories bars in barchart for the same x

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm using the same code to plot the same data, but in one plot they have a label, and in the other, other labels, based on *specular* conditions.
Even though I'm using the same code, the color and the arrangement of bars is different, leading me in total confusion.
How can I recolor and resort for consistency?
[image: Rule1]
[image: Rule2]

Each dataset, is like...but with different labels, based on different rules.
I'll count the label occurrences per day, per seller.

```
day  seller  difference label
0    0      23    1.786352     B
0    0      24    1.786352     B
0    0      26    1.786352     B
0    0      41   -1.818843     A
0    0      48    1.786352     B
0    0     180    5.174198     C
0    0     407    3.847499     C
```

Then the dataframe which counts:

```
 seller label  count
0       23     A      0
1       23     B     12
2       23     C     78
3       24     A     30
4       24     B     29
```

And the code for plotting:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5), dpi = 300)
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.barplot(data = data_frame, x = 'seller', y = 'count', hue = 'label', palette = 'deep')\
                .set(title='Distribution of A / B / C score among sellers for product {} in Q{}'.format(product_id, quarter))
plt.show()
```

#### CLARIFICATION

Hello salaman. Thanks for your reply.

I have one dataset with some values.
Then, I set two rules, which assign ABC labels differently, so I duplicate the dataframe and for the same observation, one dataframe, will have some labels and the other some others.

**Different counts are allowed, because I've two dataset whose values ABC depends on two different conditions.**

**I only would like that the bar A, will be always the blue one and the leftmost, for both plots; the bar C, the rightmost and the green one.**

Comment: This is not just a problem related to color of labels and arrangements. As you can see for the seller 23 label A there are 0 counts in the first plot and around 58 in the second plot. Same goes for other sellers. Even if the labels where mismatched there would still be consistency in distribution within sellers for each label. So, there is either something wrong with your code or the data that you are trying to plot.

Comment: Thanks salaman, added a small clarification.

Comment: Thanks salaman. Now the box is populated with "ABC" sorted in both plot, but color lines associated are grey, so bar don't match in color and position.
Both plots have only the same legend

Comment: The updated solution should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `sns.barplot()` code change the palette from `deep` to:

```
palette = ['tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:green']
```

```
sns.barplot(data = df, x = 'seller', y = 'count', hue = 'label', palette = ['tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:green'], hue_order=['A', 'B', 'C'])\
                .set(title='Distribution of A / B / C score among sellers for product {} in Q{}'.format(product_id, quarter))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks salaman. 
That partially worked: in one plot I put
`'tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:green'`
and in the other
`'tab:green', 'tab:red', 'tab:blue'`
But no changes in sorting. In one, A column is the rightmost, C is the leftmost; in the other, viceversa, Do you have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @gingerbread_54 For that you need to specify the ```hue_order``` parameter as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: A well deserved big up for you. 
Thanks salaman, appreciated

Comment: It's no bother. Glad to help you out.